# Why I can't add an .svg file with effects such as drop shadows, blurs, and color matrix in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

Why I can't add an `.svg` file with effects such as drop shadows, blurs, and color matrix as a drawable resource in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Because Android's drawables are not SVG. You can create xml drawables fron SVGs. The format of Android's vector drawablea is similar to SVG, but it is not the same.

If you want all the effects you mentioned, you'll probably have to create bitmap images in various resolutions in a graphics program that fully supports SVG and use those bitmap images (PNG for instance) for your app, putting them in the correct drawables folders.